# How to avoid of hourglass mouse cursor when executing SQL query with TFDQuery in Delphi XE5

Tags: delphi, firedac

I have grid control on form and when current record change i need to load RTF stored in DB. It works fine in general, but when i switch records i can see changes of mouse cursor to hourglass and back to regular:

```
function TComments.GetDocument(AID: integer; ADst: TStream):Boolean;
begin
  try
    SelectQuery.Close;
    SelectQuery.Params.Clear;
    SelectQuery.SQL.Text :=
      'SELECT Dokument from Kommentarer ' +
      'WHERE ID = :ID';
    SelectQuery.ParamByName('ID').AsInteger := AID;
    SelectQuery.Open;
    Result := SelectQuery.RecordCount > 0;
    if Result then
      (SelectQuery.Fields[0] as TBLOBField).SaveToStream(ADst);
  finally
    SelectQuery.Close;
  end;
end;
```

If i comment "SelectQuery.Open;" then cursor doesn't switch. I supposed there should be option in TFDQuery (or connection), but i can't find anything. Any help?

UPDATE. As TLama suggested, i placed WaitCursor:TFDGUIxWaitCursor at my form (one place for app) and use it this way:

```
  StoredCursor := WaitCursor.ScreenCursor;
  WaitCursor.ScreenCursor := gcrNone;
  try
    // access DB with queries
  finally
    WaitCursor.ScreenCursor := StoredCursor;
  end;
```

UPDATE2: Two more ways to do it.

1. Set `TFDQuery.ResourceOptions.SilentMode=True` (simplest way to disable hourglass cursor for specific queries, property name is bad, but according to doc it doesn't block any dialogs, only changes of cursor).
2. Set global variable `FADGUIxSilentMode=True` from unit FireDAC.UI.Intf (not best, but probably simplest way to disable changes of cursor globally for FireDAC).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is covered in [`this FAQ`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/GUI_Questions_(FireDAC)) set:

> **How can I turn off the SQL hourglass completely ?**
>
> a) To disable the wait cursor completely for an application, use
>   [TFDGUIxWaitCursor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FireDAC.Comp.UI.TFDGUIxWaitCursor) with [Provider](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FireDAC.Comp.UI.TFDGUIxComponent.Provider) = 'Console'. The 'Console'
>   provider contains an empty wait cursor implementation and the wait
>   cursor will no longer be shown by FireDAC. If a mouse cursor is still
>   changing, then check that only FireDAC.ConsoleUI.Wait unit is included
>   into your application and FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait and FireDAC.FMXUI.Wait
>   are not included. Note that you will not have the ability to turn the
>   wait cursor on again.
>
> b) To disable the wait cursor, but to have the ability to enable it
>   again later, use code like the following:
>
> ```
> FDWaitCursor1.ScreenCursor := gcrNone;
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> FDManager.ResourceOptions.SilentMode := True;
> ```
>
> c) To disable the wait cursor and FireDAC dialogs, but to have the
>   ability to enable them again later, set the [FDManager.SilentMode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomManager.SilentMode)
>   property to **True**. This will disable all wait cursors and FireDAC
>   dialogs, including:
>
> - The error dialog
> - Async execution dialog
> - Login dialog
> - Script progress dialog
>
> Setting [ResourceOptions.SilentMode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDResourceOptions.SilentMode) to **True** disables only wait
>   cursors.

Since you want to turn off that cursor only for that query execution, use the option b and wrap your code with something like this:

```
var
  OldCursor: TFDGUIxScreenCursor;
begin
  OldCursor := FDWaitCursor1.ScreenCursor;
  FDWaitCursor1.ScreenCursor := gcrNone;
  try
    // your code goes here
  finally
    FDWaitCursor1.ScreenCursor := OldCursor;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I need to disable mouse cursor changes only in this particular place, not for whole app. Your first suggestion to use TFDGUIxWaitCursor works fine, thank you! Could you put it as solution?

Comment: You're welcome! You were faster with (the same) code example :-)